# Need a batch script for moving modified files from one folder to another

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have moved 10 files into a folder at 10:15. Of them I have modified(changed a string in them) 6 files by a batch file at 10:30.
I need to have a list and count of files modified and need to move the modified files to another folder.

I have tried the one below. But it is copying all the files in the folder irrespective of time.

```
ECHO OFF
set source=C:\Users\john\Desktop\abc\
set destination=C:\Users\john\Desktop\xyz\

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd1=%%j"."%%i"."%%k

if exist %destination% goto GO
:GO
mkdir %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
xcopy %source%* %destination% /s/d/y/c/v/r
echo. 
echo Finished copying %source% to %destination%
echo.
echo Created %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
pause
```

Thanks for the help. I need the above function to happen only in a batch file.

Comment: `robocopy /xo` will only copy newer files

Comment: I tried it. but it is copying all the files irrespective of time

Comment: Well, the difference is obviously only in time, not date. So if all files have the same last modification __date__ and just last modification __time__ is different, this approach won't work for you. If you would have used `/M` on running `xcopy` the first time which removes the archive attributes from all copied files, then it would be easy to code a loop which moves the files with archive attribute set again because of a modification. But why do you need a batch file at all for this task? Moving 6 files once should not be difficult to do with Windows Explorer.